Web.2 vs. Web.3 Solana Gas Stations - which are people building?
I'm developing an application that requires a gas station to pay user's gas fees. I'm new to Solana, and unclear on whether it's best practice to implement the solution as a Solana program or a traditional server application.
Is there any leading thought, or best practice, behind building a Solana gas station?
